# Send Request with Image to Tensorflow Server API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I am working on an ID card detection system, Actually, I trained the model, I want to server this model in order to be  able to send an API  request to it, so I followed this tutorial
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple
the server is working now, but my problem is I need to send an image to this  server, and then I want  it to return with true/false result as if this image is an ID card or not,
how can I do that?
this is my  python script where I want to send a request to the server with an image

```
import json
import requests
data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": "test_images/image1.png"})
print('Data: {} ... {}'.format(data[:50], data[len(data)-52:]))
IMAGE_NAME = 'test_images/image1.png'


headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
json_response = requests.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/saved_model:predict', data=data, headers=headers)
predictions = json.loads(json_response.text)
print(predictions)
```

I am not sure about what instance meaning  and  of course, I get this error when trying to send a request

> {'error': 'JSON Value: {\n    "signature_name": "serving_default",\n    "instances": "test_images/image1.png"\n} Excepting 'instances' to be an list/array'}

The model is trained and loaded to the server successfully, my question is how can I check if the image is ID card or not using the model

Comment: it looks like the data is not read properly. check your json.dumps(...) if it correctly reads the image and if it is in list/ array format

Comment: is my request true while I am sending post request to it  ?

Comment: based on the error you have received, the problem is only the data you send, so I guess yes

Comment: {'error': 'Failed to process element: 0 of \'instances\' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON Value: "test_images/image1.png" Type: String is not of expected type: uint8'}
this is the error that  I get when I put the  image in array

Comment: right now  the script can read  the json but I get this error {'error': 'Input shape axis 0 must equal 4, got shape [3]\n\t [[{{node Preprocessor/map/while/ResizeToRange/cond/resize_1/unstack}}]]'}

Comment: Looks like you are missing one image there. Sorry cannot follow more> I need full code, model and sample images to debug